Help with Valid TACH Count meaning in EMC2301?
I have started working with an EMC2301 with a fan, and I got some starting code, that set up the device for min RPM = 500, via bits RNGx in REGISTER 6-13: (0x32) FAN CONFIG - FAN CONFIGURATION REGISTER in the EMC2301 datasheet, which means I can use the "Table 7.2 Tachometer Count to RPM Look Up Table (Range = 500 RPM)" in AN 17.4 RPM to TACH Counts Conversion.
So, basically that sample code worked - I can start the fan at low RPM, then change it to max RPM, then stop/turn off the fan, good. But then I realized that code never sets the Valid TACH Count Register (REGISTER 6-19: (0x39) VALID TACH - MAXIMUM VALID TACH COUNTS REGISTER), and so I tried to read a bit on it - but I cannot really say I understand it; hopefully someone can clarify or confirm which of my guesses are correct.

4.4.2 VALID TACHOMETER READINGS
The Valid TACH Count registers store the maximum
TACH Reading Register value to indicate that each fan
is spinning properly. The value is referenced at the end
of the Spin Up Routine to determine if the fan has
started operating and decide if the device needs to
retry. See Section 4.4.1 “Tachometer Counts to
RPM” for translating the count to an RPM.

Ok, so I guess that, if this is only for "the maximum TACH Reading Register value to indicate that each fan is spinning properly", then it is related to min RPM only? And Table 7.2 gives me these values for around 500 RPM (note tach counts and RPM are inversely proportional):



TACH COUNT (DECIMAL)
TACH HIGH BYTE (HEX)
FAN SPEED (RPM)




7840
F5
502


7872
F6
500


7904
F7
497



What puzzles me here is:

If I already had to specify min RPM = 500 via RNGx in REGISTER 6-13, why do I again have to specify more-less the same in REGISTER 6-19? Couldn't they have just said "Even if you've specified min RPM in REGISTER 6-13, you still have to repeat that choice via max TACH counts in REGISTER 6-19 using the corresponding entry in tables from AN 17.4"?
So, assuming my case of min RPM = 500, should I just pick the corresponding TACH HIGH BYTE (HEX) entry in the table, that in 0xF6, and use that as value for The Valid TACH Count - or should I actually measure what is achievable with that controller + fan combo (e.g. by setting Tach Target, and then later reading corresponding Tach Measurement)?
"indicate that each fan is spinning properly" could be understood to be valid for any and all target RPM values, beyond the min RPM one - say if I want to set target RPM of 1000? In that case should I set the Valid TACH Count register each time I change the RPM (by setting a new target TACH)? Or do they mean its only related to min RPM (in which case, I would have used "... each fan has started spinning" wording instead)?

I found this code EMC2301/EMC2301.cpp which sets this register (here called EMC2301_REG_FANVALTACHCOUNT) only as a part of a function called setMinValidRPM, so this hints to me that Valid TACH Count register is only related to min RPM (but then, if one uses tachFanPolesMultiplier_ = 1 in that code's calculation for maxTachCount_, one gets a negative value for uint8_t without any note that they're counting on that, so it doesn't really inspire confidence for me).

If the TACH Reading Register value exceeds the Valid
TACH Count Register (indicating that the Fan RPM is
below the threshold set by this count), then a Stalled
Fan is detected. In this condition, the algorithm will
automatically begin its Spin Up Routine.

Ok, - but if I want to keep the fan OFF, then target TACH count should be on 8191 (or TACH HIGH BYTE on 0xFF); I certainly would not a Spin Up Routine in that case? Does this mean the above holds true for all values, except for target TACH HIGH BYTE = 0xFF?

If a TACH Target setting is set above the Valid TACH
Count setting, then that setting will be ignored and the
algorithm will use the current fan drive setting.

Ok, but as I mention, the first sample code I worked with never set the Valid Tach Count Register, which means it should have its Power-on-Reset (POR) value, which is 0x00. In that case, whatever value > 0x00 I'd set should have been ignored - but as I mentioned earlier, I can both turn on and turn off the fan?!

4.4.3 STALLED FAN
A stalled fan is detected if the tach counter exceeds the
user-programmable Valid TACH Count setting. If a stall
is detected, the device will flag the fan as stalled and
trigger an interrupt.
If the RPM-based Fan Speed Control algorithm is
enabled, the algorithm will automatically attempt to
restart the fan until it detects a valid tachometer level or
is disabled

Again, I guess this holds for all target values, except target TACH HIGH BYTE = 0xFF? Also, in the case where Valid Tach Count Register was unset (that is, 0x00), does that mean the fan is always considered stalled?

4.8 Spin Up Routine
When the Fan Speed Control algorithm is enabled, the
Spin Up Routine is initiated under the following
conditions:

The TACH Target Register value changes from
a value of FFh to a value that is less than the
Valid TACH Count (see Register 6-19).
The RPM-based Fan Speed Control algorithm’s
measured TACH Reading Register value is
greater than the Valid TACH Count setting.


OK, I guess this confirms that TACH Target value of 0xFF is indeed taken as special, and is not checked vs. the Valid Tach Count Register maximum; but I still cannot tell whether Valid Tach Count Register refers strictly to the maximum set by min RPM, or not ...
